# Script working in JSFiddle but not in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

so I was trying to create a minimizable div, and i  came across this JSfiddle which works great and as i need but when i create the .html // .min.js // .css it doesn't work in browser and my consoles giving no errors, here's the code i'm currently using

```
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css">
    <script src="global-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="widnow">
    <div id="title_bar">
        <div id="button">-</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

the stylesheed and jquery are exacatly the same as they are in the JSfiddle and so is the HTML and yet it's still not working.

Here's the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/miqdad/Qy6Sj/1/

Any help is great thanks!

Comment: i think jsfiddle is in the browser

Comment: Are you using the same CSS and JS and is the page finding them?

Comment: not getting any errors in console and if it didn't pick up the CSS then it wouldn't be styled which is it

Comment: [More duplicates here](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+script+works+in+jsfiddle+but+not+in+browser&gws_rd=ssl) if you're interested.